# Scala pass-through wrappers

Tags: scala, wrapper, scala-macros

Very many times, I'll want to "replace" a single method of a given object.

```
foo: Foo
foo.bar(i) // original
foo.baz(s) // replace this implementation
```

I'll wind up creating a pass-through wrapper class.

```
class FooWrapper(foo: Foo) extends Foo {
  def bar(i: Int) = foo.bar(i)
  def baz(s: String) = foo.baz(s)
}
```

And then

```
foo: Foo
val foo2 = new FooWrapper(foo) { def baz(s: String) = ... }
foo2.bar(i)
foo2.baz(s)
```

This works with traits and classes, and works without modifying the source code of the type.

I use this quite a bit, particularly when adapting libraries or other bits of code.

This can get tedious with lots of methods. The other day, I wanted to replace the `shutdown` method on an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instance, and I had to do this for a dozen methods.

Is this a common idiom, or is this normally done another way? I suspect this could be done nicely with a macro, though I haven't found any existing ones that do this.

Comment: what's wrong with inheritance? class Foo2 extends Foo { override def baz = ??? }

Comment: @Maxim, sorry, I should have clarified. That doesn't work for types that are interfaces or abstract classes. Plus, the instance has *already* been constructed somewhere else, like in a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with [AOP (Aspect-oriented programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)

There're many libraries to do so, try this one -
https://github.com/adamw/scala-macro-aop

- Note that this library is in POC stage for now so you might look for something more mature. I've put it here because I think it shows the concept very clearly.

For your example you'll have to do something like

```
class FooWrapper(@delegate wrapped: Foo) extends Foo {
  def baz(i: Int) = ???
}
```

Comment: Oh...POC, huh? It hasn't been updated since September 2013, so it might be dead.